# Disable Yaml header output on Pandoc markdown

Tags: yaml, markdown, pandoc

I've been using [apostrophe](https://github.com/ApostropheEditor/Apostrophe), it shows metadata on the beginning of the file. Probably this is a new feature on Pandoc markdown.
I glanced many [options](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables) but couldn't find any [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26395374/what-can-i-control-with-yaml-header-options-in-pandoc) to disable it.

How can I disable to printing YAML header on Markdown alongside entering this metadata which need to enter PDF info.

```markdown
---
   lang: En-GB   
   date: 15.06.2021
   author: max  
   subtitle: 'How to disable YAML header printing as header'
   title: "Markdown Tutorial"                       
   geometry: margin=3cm
   fontfamily: default
   fontsize: 12pt

...
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps try ending the [YAML metadata block](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-yaml_metadata_block) with three backticks as well (instead of three dots). Or if the Apostrophe editor doesn't understand that either, I humbly suggest [PanWriter](https://panwriter.com).